# combining links into one

Tags: java, php, html

I was wondering the best method and language to use for combining individual links into one "link?"

i.e. Normally the links are separated one by one in an email so you have to click each link individually, now I want to have it so the links are combined into one, so the user doesn't have to click each individual link but rather a "link."

Comment: Ideally using your situation I would have to link to an unique external pre-generated php page that had written all the links with an _automatic_ click on an link element to load <?php include("link1,link2,link3"); ?> that sounds ideal, ideally I could run an AJAX loader while the links where being clicked but not activated in an browser...

So the combined links into one would require a pre-generated link to a php page that held the include() statement?

Comment: I think you want like this.

`function test()
{
   var links = 'http://google.com,http://stackoverflow.com';     
          // Give all your links separate with comma
   var s = links.split(",");
   for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++)
   {
 window.open(s[i], '_blank');
   } 
}`
Call this function wherever you want.It will open all url's. May be it helps you.

Comment: @ Gowri - Is there a way to keep track of the links initial response, i.e. page loaded successfully, or page loaded successfully and send back X response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming by "link" you mean a URL. A URL is a locator for a single resource (eg. web page). Typically when clicked, a browser window opens and the requested resource is presented. It does not open multiple browser windows and present multiple resources by itself.

You may be able to solve the problem by creating a URL to a web page that contains javascript to open multiple browser windows/tabs, each with the appropriate URL/resource.

If they are activation links, then you could use AJAX on a single web page to iteratively request each of the URLs in turn.

Comment: You are correct in assuming I meant URL when saying "link." I like your strategy in theory, however that might get a little cumbersome after 100+ links, as essentially each link is an activation link for an individual product.